# Google Sheets Concatenation to Json

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm concatenating a set of data into single cells, making it look like a json. I want to actually turn that into a json file. [In this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PYAMTMcqICSGWk9xKnVg-66a8R3EGRNBS1OXCvi3e1A/edit#gid=0) I've prepared a sample data set (note that there are two sheets, one with the data and one with the concatenations).

Basically, I have this three cells and I want to turn each of them into a different json file.
[image]

I've tried some add-ons such as [ExportSheetData](https://github.com/Synthoid/ExportSheetData), but I didn't manage to make the file look like what I wanted it to look.

What would be the best way to make this json exportation from google sheets? Could I make that using a script or I would need to make it manually (copy into a txt file and throw in a txt-to-json converter in the web)?

Comment: You can do this with apps script.

Comment: @TheMaster how could I do it? Example sheet is open for editing if you'd like :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  ui.createMenu('foo')
  .addItem('export cell', 'exportJson')
  .addToUi();
}  

function exportJson() {
  const filename = Browser.inputBox('enter filename');
  if (!filename) return;
  
  const jsonStr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell().getDisplayValue();
  DriveApp.createFile(filename, jsonStr);
}
```

Comment: Managed to create the file, however it is coming without the active cell content. It comes only with "Range" on it. What am I doing wrong? I've left the sheet open for editing

Comment: @abutremutante `.getActiveCell().getValue()`